# Не синхронизированная работа клавиш громкости и увеличение размера шрифта (Java)

Tags: java, android

Захотел снимать нажатия с клавиш громкости на телефоне и в зависимости от того какая из двух нажата увеличивать или уменьшать размер шрифта textview, но столкнулся с проблемой, что нажатия на кнопки и действия с текстовым полем не всегда происходит синхронно, а именно обратное действие происходит, когда я перехожу с одной клавиши на другую. Это заключается в том, что когда нажата клавиша + происходит уменьшение размера, а после этого все хорошо увеличивается. Хотелось бы узнать как это можно убрать?

```
package com.example.arseny.songbook;

import ...

import static com.example.arseny.songbook.R.id.textView;

public class Activity_Two extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count = 22;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);       
        textView.setText("text");
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        TextView textViewr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textViewr.setTextSize(count);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if(count<66) {
                    count = count + 2;
                    return true;
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if(count>9) {
                    count = count - 2;
                    return true;
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                        < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Заранее спасибо за любую активность!

Comment: вместо return true; попробуйте поставить break за скобкой, чтобы всегда возвращался super...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто вовремя обновлять размер шрифта. А у вас count поменялся а шрифт меняется только при следующем нажатии.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    TextView textViewr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    //textViewr.setTextSize(count);
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if(count<66) {
                count = count + 2;
textViewr.setTextSize(count);////<<<----
                return true;
            }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if(count>9) {
                count = count - 2;
textViewr.setTextSize(count);////<<<----
                return true;
            }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
                    && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```